# VB.net Compilation error in Tuple.Create

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function CreateSelector(Of T)(propertyNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Func(Of T, Object)
    Dim sourceType = GetType(T)
    Dim parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "e")
    Dim properties = propertyNames.[Select](Function(name) Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name)).ToArray()
    Dim selector = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))(Expression.[Call](GetType(Tuple), "Create", properties.[Select](Function(p) p.Type).ToArray(), properties), parameter)
    Return selector.Compile()
End Function

Public Function Join(Of T)(left As IEnumerable(Of T), right As IEnumerable(Of T), propertyNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of T, T))
    Dim keySelector = CreateSelector(Of T)(propertyNames)
    Return left.Join(right, keySelector, keySelector, Tuple.Create)
End Function
```

When I compile the above code I get an error

> Error 18  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Create' accepts this number of arguments.

Above code is working properly in C#. After converting to VB.NET I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are not required in VB when calling functions.

For this reason providing just the function name, without parentheses, cannot be used to get the address of/delegate to that function, it is still counted as a call.

There is a separate operator in VB.NET for this:

```
Return left.Join(right, keySelector, keySelector, AddressOf Tuple.Create)
```

Comment: Thank u it corrects my error. I am getting one more error in vb.net while calling this `Join`. `Dim Fields As String() = DuplicateExpression.[Select](Function(x) x.ExpressionName).ToArray()
                Dim JoinExp = list1.Join(list2, Fields)`. error is `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' accepts this number of arguments.`

Comment: @Pradu Apparently you meant `Join` to be an extension method, in which case you must apply `<Extension>` attribute in VB.NET.